# How to explode from and to from date using laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to explode from and to from date please help me how can do that thank u.

**controller**

```
   public function index(Request $request)
    {   
        return $request->date; // date: {from: "2023/03/01", to: "2023/03/02"}

        $from = "2023/03/01";
        $to  = "2023/03/02";
   
    }
```

Comment: exclude or explode? please correct your qustion

Comment: Do you mean that `$request->date` is JSON, and you want to access `from` and `to`?  If yes, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php. If not, please edit your question and clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse dates with your specific format using `createFromFormat()`.

```
$from = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $request->date['from']);
$to = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $request->date['to']);
```

Comment: Attempt to read property "from" on array

Comment: Changed the answer assumed it was an object as you showed it as an object.